# Importing-Skype-contacts using web-API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I want to import my Skype contact using Web-API.
I did some R & D but its was not fruitful to me.

So I would like to know that is it possible to do?
And if yes, then please provide me that how this could be achieved?

Answer (score 2):

Skype has announced that they will close their API by the end of this month (31st July 2014). After that point, the only way to integrate Skype is through URIs. From the documentation, these only allow the initiation of calls and messages.

There is no way to export your skype contacts through the API or through the URI interface. Your only option is to use the Skype client to export the contacts manually. You might be able to write code that can automate this, although I'm not the right person to ask how to do this.

Comment: can you please provide link or detail of this announcement. Thanks!